# Is it possible to declare a property raising PropertyChanged event using a syntax similar to an auto-property ({ get; set; })?

Tags: c#, properties, inotifypropertychanged

I'm wondering how to simplify the use of properties when they must raise the `PropertyChanged` event. I mean as soon as you need to raise the event, the setter must do it, hence the property cannot be an auto-property. This causes some complication of the code, especially when there are multiple properties concerned, for no other purpose than to simply raise the event:

```
protected FlowDocument document;
protected bool hyphenation = true;
protected bool optimalParagraphs = true;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public FlowDocument Document { get => document; set { document = value; RaisePropertyChanged (); } }
public bool Hyphenation { get => hyphenation; set { hyphenation = value; RaisePropertyChanged (); } }
public bool OptimalParagraphs { get => optimalParagraphs; set { optimalParagraphs = value; RaisePropertyChanged (); } }

// Raise event
protected void RaisePropertyChanged ([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));
}
```

The complication is within this part which is repeated for each property:

```
protected FlowDocument document;
public FlowDocument Document { get => document; set { document = value; RaisePropertyChanged (); } }
```

because there is no possibility to express it like:

```
public FlowDocument Document { get; setAndRaiseEvent; }
```

A search on the site proposes this similar, but not duplicate, question:

- [Is it possible to use attributes to automatically raise an event on a property change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/980520/774575)

With current C# possibilities, is there a way to simplify the original code? (I'm enlarging the scope to any possibility).

Comment: Without using AOP (like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/), [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody), or others), no. You can generate code at runtime using reflection emit, which might work if you do it correctly, but there is nothing out of the box in the C# language, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"With current C# possibilities"? No.

But if you install the [`Fody`](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) and `PropertyChanged.Fody` NuGet packages and add a file named "FodyWeavers.xml" with the following contents to your project:

```
<Weavers>
    <PropertyChanged />
</Weavers>
```

...`Fody` will inject code that raises the `PropertyChanged` event into all property setters of all classes that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` when you build the project.

Please refer to [GitHub](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) for more information.